# How to fix the "unknown authentication response: 10" in postGIS database through using docker

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, postgis, imposm

I tried to import an `.osm.pbf` file into a PostGIS database by using the [kartoza/postgis](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/) dockerhub in windows. But I'm facing the error

`opening database: opening db: ping Postgres DB: pq: unknown authentication response: 10`

But the same credentials are working when I use the `docker exec` command:

```sh
docker exec -it postgis psql postgres://docker:docker@<IP>/gis
```

Here is my `config.json` file and located in `app` directory

```
{
    "cachedir": "./imposm_cache",
    "diffdir": "./imposm_dif",
    "connection": "postgres://docker:docker@<IP>:5432/gis",
    "mapping": "app/mapping.yml",
    "srid": 4326
}
```

Here is my shell script to run

```sh
imposm import -config app/config.json -read pbf-example/andorra-latest.osm.pbf -write -optimize
```

Please suggest to me how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 9):

You have to upgrade the PostgreSQL driver or library on the client side so that it supports the `scram-sha-256` authentication method introduced in PostgreSQL v10.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.9 version

Comment: I am talking about the client.

Comment: yeah my client also psql (11.8 (Debian 11.8-1.pgdg100+1)) version

Comment: No, it isn't. You may have PostgreSQL v11 installed, but this software is using something else.Try to describe the software stack

Comment: I downgraded my postgres vesrsion into 11.8 and it's working fine. Thank you

Comment: That must be by accident. You should update the Go PostgreSQL driver (specifically, the version of `libpq` it is linked with).